# Invoking non-async methods from async methods while maintaining high availability

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a `ASP.NET Core` web application with `async` controllers. I'm referencing and invoking methods in an `ASP.NET Core` project that does not use asynchronous programming (no `async`) that performs IO-bound work.

The ideal solution would be to refactor the referenced project to use asynchronous programming. However, I'm facing severe time constraints.

Microsoft documentation [advices against](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#recognize-cpu-bound-and-io-bound-work) creating tasks with `Task.Run` to perform IO-bound work. It also [advices against](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-5.0#avoid-blocking-calls) immediately awaiting results from `Task.Run`.

My question is - is there other alternative in this scenario, where I can invoke the non-async methods without refactoring and without creating a thread, while maintaining high availability?

Answer (score 3):

> is there other alternative in this scenario, where I can invoke the non-async methods without refactoring and without creating a thread, while maintaining high availability?

Your options are:

1. Call them directly. You'll be blocking a thread on the I/O work because the methods are synchronous.
2. Make the methods asynchronous.

Comment: Is calling the methods directly advisable over running them on a new thread with Task.Run? Thank you.

Comment: @user11081980: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to way would be to do to put the Non-Syncronous method inside a `Task.Run` command:

```
async Task<IActionResult> MyControllerMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

    var str = await Task.Run(() => 
    { 
        return MyReturnMethod(); 
    
    }, cancellationToken);
    
    await Task.Run (() => MyVoidMethod(), cancellationToken);
}


public string MyReturnMethod() {...}

public void MyVoidMethod() {...}
```

Note the Cancellation Token is optional, but is highly recommended. Also you don't need to pass a variable into the API endpoint. If it is from a web request it's auto generated.